# Fourier Transform (super-fancy) "f"?

Tags: math-operators

What's a "fancy" `f` I can use to denote a Fourier transform?
(I mean something fancier than what `\mathcal{F}` provides.)

Comment: I don't know how Fourier transforms are usually denoted, but another way to get a fancier `F` than `\mathcal` provides is to use the `\mathscr` command provided by the `mathrsfs` package.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: Ahh, that looks even better! (Correction: at least it does on Xetex, which I use locally. But apparently the renderer I used online for my answer below shows the same rendering for my answer as Xetex does for your answer. But it's definitely not any worse than `mathfrak`!) Please post it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

(Added as answer by request of the OP)

One way to get a fancier `F` than `\mathcal` provides is to use the `\mathscr` command provided by the `mathrsfs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,amsmath}   %The amsmath package is included for \xrightarrow
\begin{document}
\[\delta(t) \xrightarrow{\mathscr{F}} 1\]
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: mathscr MWE]

To compare other fancy `F`s: `\mathfrak{F}` from the `amssymb` package gives

[image]

`\mathcal` gives

[image: mathcal MWE]

Answer (score 6):

I found `\mathfrak{F}` looks decent.

[image]

Comment: The image doesn't show `\mathfrak{F}`

Comment: @egreg: I got it from here: http://www.texify.com/img/%5CLARGE%5C%21%5Cmathfrak%20F.gif

Comment: Well, that's a script alphabet, not Fraktur.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @MMA: I **am** the author.

Comment: @Mehrdad That does not mean that you can not comment on your own post or edit it to append additional information.

Comment: @MMA: But it certainly does mean my post in fact answered my question.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I repeat, this **is** a complete answer to my question. I'm sorry that it's too short for your taste.

Comment: @mma I am not very glad with the short answer as well, but look at the edit history. It didn't bother anybody for 1.5 years.